# Update the dataframe if record exist and extract unmatched record in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframe. In 1st dataframe is having full record and 2nd dataframe is incremental data. Need to create logic that if new record should insert in parent dataframe and existing record should replace by incremental record.

Example:

parent_df:

```
id     src_nm
10     resource_mg
15     accessible
17     nominated
18     emerging
19     deploying
```

Increment_df:

```
id     src_nm
18     accessible
19     production
23     migration
25     running
```

below result I want:

parent_df should update/insert by increment_df & unmatched record should be those record which is present in parent_df but not in increment_df. Thanks in advance!!

unmatched_df:

```
id     src_nm
10     resource_mg
15     accessible
17     nominated
```

parent_df:

```
id     src_nm
10     resource_mg
15     accessible
17     nominated
18     accessible
19     production
23     migration
25     running
```

Comment: https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/join-in-pyspark-merge-inner-outer-right-left-join-in-pyspark/  

unmatched: joined with `left_anti`, parent: joined with `outer`

Comment: can u send me demo code for that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

When you want some data that exists in one side but not in other side with a certain lookup column, you can use `left_anti` JOIN.

```py
unmatched_df = parent_df.join(increment_df, on='id', how='left_anti')
```

For parent_df, you need a little more step than just joining. You want all data from both side with updating the overlap, in this case, you first join with `outer`, which is to get all records from both. Then use `coalesce`.

```py
parent_df = (parent_df.join(increment_df, on='id', how='outer')
             .select('id', F.coalesce(increment_df.src_nm, parent_df.src_nm).alias('src_nm')))
```

Ref:

```
coalesce(col1, col2, col3)

# If col1 is not null, take value from col1.
# If col1 is null and col2 is not null, take value from col2.
# If col1 and col2 are null, take value from col3.
```